# Create new column in pandas depending on multiple conditions

Tags: pandas, loops

I would like to create a new column based on various conditions

Let's say I have a df where column A can equal any of the following: ['Single', 'Multiple', 'Commercial', 'Domestic', 'Other'], column B has numeric values from 0-30.

I'm trying to get column C to be 'Moderate' if A = 'Single' or 'Multiple', and if it equals anything else, to consider the values in column B. If column A != 'Single' or 'Multiple', column C will equal Moderate if 3 < B > 19 and 'High' if B>=19.

I have tried various loop combinations but I can't seem to get it. Any help?

```
trial = []
for x in df['A']: 
    if x == 'Single' or x == 'Multiple':
        trial.append('Moderate') 
    elif x != 'Single' or x != 'Multiple':
        if df['B']>19:
                trial.append('Test') 


df['trials'] = trial
```

Thank you kindly,

Denisse

Comment: Please provide sample data.

Answer (score 0):

It will good if you provide some sample data. But with some that I created, you can see how to *apply* a function to each row of your DataFrame.

#### Data

```py
valuesA = ['Single', 'Multiple', 'Commercial', 'Domestic', 'Other',
           'Single', 'Multiple', 'Commercial', 'Domestic', 'Other']
valuesB = [0, 10, 20, 25, 30, 25, 15, 10, 5, 3 ]

df  = pd.DataFrame({'A': valuesA, 'B': valuesB})
```

```
|    | A          |   B |
|---:|:-----------|----:|
|  0 | Single     |   0 |
|  1 | Multiple   |  10 |
|  2 | Commercial |  20 |
|  3 | Domestic   |  25 |
|  4 | Other      |  30 |
|  5 | Single     |  25 |
|  6 | Multiple   |  15 |
|  7 | Commercial |  10 |
|  8 | Domestic   |   5 |
|  9 | Other      |   3 |
```

#### Function to apply

You don't specify what happen if column B is less than or equal to 3, so I suppose that C will be 'Low'. Adapt the function as you need. Also, maybe there is a typo in your question where you say '3 < B > 19', I changed to  '3 < B < 19'.

```py
def my_function(x):
    if x['A'] in ['Single', 'Multiple']:
        return 'Moderate'
    else:
        if x['B'] <= 3:
            return 'Low'
        elif 3 < x['B'] < 19:
            return 'Moderate'
        else:
            return 'High'
```

#### New column

With the DataFrame and the new function you can apply it to each row with the method apply using the argument 'axis=1':

```py
df['C'] = df.apply(my_function, axis=1)
```

```
|    | A          |   B | C        |
|---:|:-----------|----:|:---------|
|  0 | Single     |   0 | Moderate |
|  1 | Multiple   |  10 | Moderate |
|  2 | Commercial |  20 | High     |
|  3 | Domestic   |  25 | High     |
|  4 | Other      |  30 | High     |
|  5 | Single     |  25 | Moderate |
|  6 | Multiple   |  15 | Moderate |
|  7 | Commercial |  10 | Moderate |
|  8 | Domestic   |   5 | Moderate |
|  9 | Other      |   3 | Low      |
```

Comment: Hello Augusto, Thank you for this detailed answer. I tried the function, entering my df as the value x, and I got this error:
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Would you know what I did wrong?

Comment: The argument x it's not a DataFrame, it is a row's DataFrame. That the reason why you must send the function through the method apply() from a DataFrame. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html